# What is a Punctured disk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, terminology, hodge-theory

What is a punctured disk? I am reading Voisin Book (Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry) and  I found this term and  I would like to know what is it. Thank you!!

Comment: It is what you get when you drop an $\epsilon$ ball on a thorny mathematics problem.

Answer (score 5):

It just means a disk minus a point (or *the* disk minus *the* point). Most often this means $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:0<x^2+y^2\le 1\}$, but occasionally people mean the open disk $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:0<x^2+y^2<1\}$

Comment: Just one minor addition: in the context of complex geometry (as is mentioned in the question), this is usually viewed as a subset of $\Bbb C$ rather than just $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: True. Since this is tagged algebraic topology, if it wasn't clear to OP, the two are topologically the same.